# Javascript UI Toolkit

Tags: javascript, user-interface, toolkit

I'm looking for a light-weight UI toolkit written in Javascript (something like Swing) but I'd rather not use ExtJS because I fear that will slow things down tremendously. Are there any small UI toolkits out there that mainly focus on layouts?

The problems I face in particular are working with layouts. A lot of toolkits come with different layout styles (Floating, Grid, Split Panes) and that is quite hard with CSS (especially heights extending 100%). It's also to be used as a framework for other developers to easily create layouts and just apply their own CSS (for themes).

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some examples of things you want that you can't do in CSS.  If you can do it in CSS, do it there...what on top of/beyond that do you need a library for? (It's a valid question, but there are lots out there, more information would help get you a better answer)

Comment: You may find it useful to look into this SO question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323347/jquery-ui-without-html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try, [UKI Simple UI Kit](http://ukijs.org/)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at http://qooxdoo.org as well.

---

Edited: If it's just about layout, did you consider using just a CSS framework (e. g. Blueprint)?

This is a great tool for building CSS http://compass-style.org.

Answer (score 1):

You can look into one of the following

- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) (components)
- [Sproutcore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) (full framework)
- [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org/) (full framework, written in Objective-j, interpreted to JS)
- [Google webtoolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) (written in java, compiled to JS)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery gzips its minified version to about 24k, and is as robust as you will need for that 24k. You can also link your pages to it through Google's hosting.

Comment: jQuery isn't a UI toolkit and jQuery UI is no where near one either.

Comment: @Louis - Define "toolkit" :)  That's a *very* ambiguous word.

Comment: Ha yeah I was wondering what the proper name was. Basically Tkinter, Swing. The UI thingomajigos :P