# Instance Eval in Javascript around browsers

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, metaprogramming, dsl, jaml

From [Coffeekup](http://github.com/mauricemach/coffeekup/blob/master/lib/coffeekup.coffee#L48) and [JAML](http://github.com/edspencer/jaml/blob/master/Jaml-all.js#L231)'s source, (while working on [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323347/jquery-ui-without-html)), we can see a way to hack ruby's [instance eval](http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/ruby-instanceeval-and-classeval-method.html) into Javascript ([JAML author explains more](http://github.com/edspencer/jaml/blob/master/Jaml-all.js#L197)). It involves decompiling the function, and evaluating it around a with block.

The question is: is this supported all around browsers/js runtimes? I know it works on firefox, opera and chrome, but toString on function is *not* [consistent among platforms](http://perfectionkills.com/those-tricky-functions/), hence the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked it out, and It does work on all browsers.